# Change Bootstrap input focus blue glow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know the how to change Bootstrap's `input:focus`? The blue glow that shows up when you click on an `input` field?

Comment: As I can see the focus selector in multiple places Im not sure were I should change it ?

Comment: Apparently @mdo is 100% against allowing us to specify the glow color with a LESS variable: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2742

Answer (score 275, accepted):

In the end I changed the following css entry in bootstrap.css

```
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {   
  border-color: rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6);
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: I have came across with targeting `input[type] {}`

Comment: This is no longer necessary with Bootstrap 3.x.  See my answer for more info.

Comment: @Cricket This variable is not currently available at the Boostrap customizer :(

Comment: @Caumons It is now.  I'd recommend using `@input-border-focus` instead of this answer.

Comment: you forgot ```select```

Comment: Its also worth mentioning that this isn't a feasible solution if you are using Bower since your will lose these changes anytime someone needs to reinstall/change bower_components.

Comment: @Cricket +1 because don't modify mixins if yopu can solve the problem through the variables.less or .sass

Comment: for me help `outline: 0 none !important` for `a,button,tr (focus)`, big thanks

Comment: Add `select` and `textarea`

Comment: What about file type?

Comment: select and text area not working. anyone?

Comment: @HerbertYeo #your_select_id select:focus // working

Answer (score 225):

You can use the `.form-control` selector to match all inputs. For example to change to red:

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #FF0000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Put it in your custom css file and load it after bootstrap.css. It will apply to all inputs including textarea, select etc...

Comment: @lonesword is right, infact you have to change both the border-color and the shadow-color. I've updated the answer

Comment: This is far cleaner than @felix001's solution, and it works

Comment: worked great for me - just added !important to the classes to overwrite bootstrap

Comment: you know what, actually there is no need to type the first sentence of code it could simply be box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6); but you must include the border line

Answer (score 77):

[image] [image]

You can modify the `.form-control:focus` **color** without altering the bootstrap style in this way:

### Quick fix

```
.form-control:focus {
        border-color: #28a745;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.25);
    }
```

### Full explanation

1. Find the bootstrapCDN version that you are using. *E.g. for me right now is 4.3.1: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css*
2. Search for the class you want to modify. *E.g. `.form-control:focus` and copy the parameters that you want to modify into your css. In this case is `border-color` and `box-shadow`.*
3. Choose a color for the `border-color`. *In this case I choose to pick up the same green the bootstrap uses for their `.btn-success` class, by searching for that particular class in the bootstrap.css page mentioned in the step 1.*
4. Convert the color you have picked to RGB and add that to the `box-shadow` parameter without altering the fourth RGBA parameter (0.25) that bootstrap has for transparency.

Comment: great, its simple and working, and i need green color too :)

Comment: This does not work for file input. Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure why, I haven't used bootstrap in a long time now. What I can suggest is to try find the input class that is being used as a default, try to understand what you need to change by modifying it.

Comment: Worked. ADDITION: if you want to style select elements, you have to add their selectors as well e.g.: `.form-control:focus,
select:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px grey;
}`

Answer (score 61):

If you are using Bootstrap 3.x, you can now change the color with the new `@input-border-focus` variable.

See [the commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/73c048578dfce7c6d4e8c9d4fe6c6bd22b2ff9b2) for more info and warnings.

In **_variables.scss** update `@input-border-focus`.

To modify the size/other parts of this glow modify the **mixins/_forms.scss**

```
@mixin form-control-focus($color: $input-border-focus) {
  $color-rgba: rgba(red($color), green($color), blue($color), .6);
  &:focus {
    border-color: $color;
    outline: 0;
    @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 4px $color-rgba);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to accomplish or do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use the Less or [Sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) versions of the Bootstrap stylesheets.  Then, set your custom variable before importing the Bootstrap stylesheets and it will override the Bootstrap defaults.  You'll either need to precompile your stylesheets or use something like [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets).

Comment: You could also make use of the official bootstrap site to make custom changes on the less variables: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Nice, but that won't apply to buttons and other links, only input and textarea, apparently. For buttons, you still need to override with `.btn:focus { outline: none; }`, for example.

Comment: This answer does work for those using SASS/SCSS. @input-order-focus is in `_variables.scss`.

Answer (score 20):

For Bootstrap v4.0.0 beta release you will need the following added to a stylesheet that overrides Bootstrap (either add in after CDN/local link to bootstrap v4.0.0 beta or add `!important` to the stylings:

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #6265e4 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(98, 101, 228, 1) !important;
}
```

Replace the border-color and the rgba on the box-shadow with which ever colour style you'd like*.

Answer (score 17):

In Bootstrap 4, if you compile SASS by yourself, you can change the following variables to control the styling of the focus shadow:

```
$input-btn-focus-width:       .2rem !default;
$input-btn-focus-color:       rgba($component-active-bg, .25) !default;
$input-btn-focus-box-shadow:  0 0 0 $input-btn-focus-width $input-btn-focus-color !default;
```

Note: as of Bootstrap 4.1, the `$input-btn-focus-color` and `$input-btn-focus-box-shadow` variables are used only for input elements, but not for buttons. The focus shadow for buttons is hardcoded as `box-shadow: 0 0 0 $btn-focus-width rgba($border, .5);`, so you can only control the shadow width via the `$input-btn-focus-width` variable.

Answer (score 12):

Here are the changes if you want Chrome to show the platform default "yellow" outline.

```
textarea:focus, input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="datetime"]:focus, input[type="datetime-local"]:focus, input[type="date"]:focus, input[type="month"]:focus, input[type="time"]:focus, input[type="week"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="color"]:focus, .uneditable-    input:focus {
    border-color: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

Comment: How can I disable the chrome yellow outline?

Comment: Actually, do NOT disable all :focus outlines (as I suggested above). It is horrible for accessibility for keyboard only users. You can disable the platform defaults as above and add in something suitably accessible: `outline: dotted thin black;` (or whatever your testing suggests works)

Answer (score 12):

To disable the blue glow (but you can modify the code to change color, size, etc), add this to your css:

```
.search-form input[type="search"] {  
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
}
```

Here's a screencapture showing the effect: before and after:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This worked for me. But I also had to add border-color since it would leave it blue.

Answer (score 10):

Simple one

To remove it:

```
.form-control, .btn {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

To change it

```
.form-control, .btn {
    box-shadow: new-value !important;
    outline: new-value !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I landed to this thread looking for the way to disable glow altogether. Many answers were overcomplicated for my purpose. For easy solution, I just needed one line of CSS as follows.

```
input, textarea, button {outline: none; }
```

Comment: I would think you might need `box-shadow: none;` as well.

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to add `!important` after the `box-shadow` suggested by @silverliebt

Answer (score 8):

Add an Id to the body tag. In your own Css (not the bootstrap.css) point to the new body ID and set the class or tag you want to override and the new properties.
Now you can update bootstrap anytime without loosing your changes.

**html file:**

```
  <body id="bootstrap-overrides">
```

**css file:**

```
#bootstrap-overrides input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, textarea:focus{
  border-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6);
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

See also: [best way to override bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in Bootstrap 4.0.0-Beta (as of October 2017) the input element isn't referenced by **input[type="text"]**, all Bootstrap 4 properties for the input element are actually **form** based.

So it's using the **.form-control:focus** styles. The appropriate code for the "on focus" highlighting of an input element is the following:

```
.form-control:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: none;
}
```

Pretty easy to implement, just change the **border-color** property.

Comment: Or if using scss, just override the $input-focus-border-color variable for bootstrap 4.0.0-Beta

Comment: I think you also need to add in to this `box-shadow: xpx ypx #80bdff;`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the shadow completely add the class `shadow-none` to your input element.

Answer (score 5):

Building up on [@wasinger's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790895/766301) above, in **Bootstrap 4.5** I had to override not only the color variables but also the `box-shadow` itself.

```
$input-focus-width: .2rem !default;
$input-focus-color: rgba($YOUR_COLOR, .25) !default;
$input-focus-border-color: rgba($YOUR_COLOR, .5) !default;
$input-focus-box-shadow: 0 0 0 $input-focus-width $input-focus-color !default;
```

Comment: In Bulma, its also the box-shadow that makes the glow.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,It's work for me.**

```
input:focus, textarea:focus{
     box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 3.3.7 you can change the @input-border-focus value in the Forms section of the customizer:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the input border before the focus. You can specify your favorite color you want to use and other css like padding etc

```
.input {
    padding: 6px 190px 6px 15px;
    outline: #2a65ea auto 105px ;
}
```

When we focus on input.  You can specify your favorite color outline you wish

```
.input:focus{
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: none;
    outline: lightgreen auto 5px ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work 100% use this:

```css
.form-control, .form-control:focus{
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
   border: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's same as bootstrap's input...

```
input:focus{
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-color: #86B7FE;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, .25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use ?

```
 input:focus{
        outline-color : #7a0ac5;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve this with CSS. It seems like Boostrap is getting the last say even though I have by site.css after bootstrap. In any event, this worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");

    Array.from(elements).forEach(function () {
        this.addEventListener("click", cbChange, false);
    })

    });

function cbChange(event) {
    var ele = event.target;
    var obj = document.getElementById(ele.id);
    obj.style.borderColor = "lightgrey";
}
```

Later I found this to work in the css. Obviously with form-controls only

```
.form-control.focus, .form-control:focus {
    border-color: gainsboro;
}
```

Here are before and after shots from Chrome Developer tool. Notice the difference in border color between focus on and focus off. On a side note, this does not work for buttons. With buttons. With buttons you have to change outline property to none.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should help remove it!

```css
input[type = text] {
  border: none;
}

input[type = text]:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, just wanted to say that the code snippet feature is not necessary here, you can use code fences to format the code instead. Have a great day, Bye!

Answer (score 0):

outline: 0;
box-shadow: none;
css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My goal was pretty simple - to align the focus glow color with my primary theme color.

For that I needed to override `$primary` variable **before** `@import "bootstrap/variables"` in my SASS and the magic happened. I believe it will work for any other theme colors (alert, danger) as well.