# CSS Class doesn't work UNLESS listed twice in the css, why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to override a bootstrap class specifically: `.container`

I have created a CSS file which I load AFTER Bootstrap.min.css.
The class in my css file is:

```
    .container {
   background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
   border-left: 1px solid #669933 !important;
   border-right: 1px solid #669933 !important;
}
```

This does nothing, BUT if I make my CSS file this:

```
.container {
   background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
   border-left: 1px solid #669933 !important;
   border-right: 1px solid #669933 !important;
}
.container {
   background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
   border-left: 1px solid #669933 !important;
   border-right: 1px solid #669933 !important;
}
```

It then works! The class is identical, but listed twice.
Why does this work only when listed twice and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create an example of this?

Comment: Try these best practices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css

Comment: What is the best way for me to provide you with an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Css always taking the first class property, so try to load first.