# How should a boilerplate LESS framework be customised?

Tags: css, less, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm building a website using the [skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) framework, using [a fork that compiles from LESS](https://github.com/whatsnewsaes/Skeleton-less).

What is the correct approach to customising the styles without losing the underlying scaffolding provided by skeleton? I understand that I can change variables such as `@font-color`, but there are no variables for font-size and certain elements need custom margins and padding.

Should I edit the LESS file or create a separate css file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css hope this can help you it's the same concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fork you mentioned ships with a single file (`less/skeleton.less`) which contains all required Less code.

You could create a new file (for instance `project.less`) which import the  `less/skeleton.less`.

project.less:

```
@import "less/skeleton";
```

Now you can override all variable declared in `less/skeleton.less` after the import directive.

```
@import "less/skeleton";
@font-color: blue;
```

Because of Less uses lazy loading and the last declaration wins rule for variables you can override a variable by putting the definition afterwards, see also: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading.

> but there are no variables for font-size and certain elements need custom >margins and padding.

You should override these properties per selector, for stance:

```
button, .button {
height: 48px; //overide button's height
}
```

or create a new class with the [extend feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)

```
.smallbutton {
&:extend(.button all);
height: 16px;
}
```

The Less code also contains some Media Queries. You should use these media queries in your code:

```
@media (min-width: @bp-larger-than-mobile) { 
.smallbutton {
&:extend(.button all);
height: 16px;
}
}
```

In stead of importing the Less code you can also use the [Less Skeleton plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/less-plugin-skeleton). After installing this plugin (`npm install less-plugin-skeleton`) you can compile your code as above without the `@import` directive.

```
lessc project.less --skeleton
```