# Background color of DT::datatable in shiny

Tags: shiny, dt

How do I change the background color of a selected row of a datatable in a shiny application? My ui.R has the following code:

```
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'title')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('dashboard', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard'))
  )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           box(
             title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
             DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
           ),
           box(
             title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
             DT::dataTableOutput('table2')
           )
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           box(
             title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
             DT::dataTableOutput('table3')
           )
    )
  )
)
dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS to do this. The color of the selected rows is set by `table.dataTable tbody tr.selected { background-color: #B0BED9;}` in `jquery.min.dataTables.css`.

Here's a minimal example based on your code on how to override it using `tags$style`:

```
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'title')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('dashboard', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard'))
  )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#table1 tr.selected, #table2 tr.selected {background-color:red}"))),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           box(
             title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
             DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
           ),
           box(
             title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
             DT::dataTableOutput('table2')
           )
    )
  )
)
ui<-dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$table1 = DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )

  output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I added the table ids (`#table1 tr.selected, #table2 tr.selected`) so that this selector has more weight than the default one and overrides it, more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css).

Comment: Could you also update your answer so that applies to `shinydashboard`? I have this table inside `box` in a `column` of a `fluidRow`.

Comment: Maybe update your question to include some code? Not sure what your app looks like.

Comment: Strange but it has no affect when I run your example app.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the screen shot [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wkrvY.png). I have no clue why @NicE solution does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe post the output of `sessionInfo()`, my guess is that we don't have the same version of packages.

Comment: OK I have figured it out. Added `!important` next to color specification as was pointed out in the link provided by @NicE.

Comment: For me it did not work with the added `!important` (I am using a nested table), however this worked `#table tr.selected td { background-color: red !important; }`