# Calling a custom css after bootstrap doesn't change it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my simple code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sub-cat.css">
```

I don't know what's exactly wrong, I wanna change "Caption" class of bootstrap I wrote my code in "sub-cat.css" and when I see the inspect elements my changes didn't apply !

Comment: Can you please share your code I can't see it here

Comment: This [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css) will help you to understand complete theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a guess, that bootstrap uses more specific selectors than you.

Like: 
`.container,.navbar-static-top .container,.navbar-fixed-top .container,.navbar-fixed-bottom .container{width:940px;}`

vs

```
.container{width:940px;}
```

if this is the case, just make sure you use the same or more precise selectors.

Another way is to use !important, but thats not the best way to go!

Answer (score 1):

use !important .. for example:

```
element{color: red !important}
```