# how to overwrite bootstrap css when bootstrap theme is choosen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages-extlib

I want to overwrite some css from Bootstrap in my application. I have chosen to run the Bootstrap theme that is included with the extension library. But if I include a css and add it to my application theme (which extends="Bootstrap3_flat") the css is overwritten. How can I fix this? I assume it is the order of loading that causes the overwritten.

Comment: Have you used !important to the end of particular style?

Comment: no, and when I did it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @Malin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `!important` at the end of your style..

Comment: Using !important is not the best way http://stackoverflow.com/a/27704409/171456

Answer (score 0):

added the important css declaration as in

```
.btn {
    margin-left:10px !important;
}
```