# Have different colors for bootstrap input glow based on page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a project and on one page I would like the input boxes glow (when clicked on) to be of a certain color and on the other page I would like the input boxes glow to be of a different color. I understand within the bootstrap.css file I can modify this code:

```
 .form-control:focus {
    border-color: #76323F;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(118,50, 63, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(118, 50, 63, 1);
}
```

to get the color I want (I have already done this). But now when an input is clicked  I want to have a different color glow depending on which page Im on. How would I do this?

Comment: You could add a class to the body tag based on what page you are on and then cascade your CSS based on that body class.

Comment: Add a new class to your stylesheet which overrides the box-shadow on elements you add the class to? Something like ```.form-control.light-shadow:focus {box-shadow: ...}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
.form-control:active {
  background:red !important; //or without important if there is no need to use it
}
```

If You want set different color for many inputs, add unique id or class for `.form-control`

Answer (score 1):

*you could use jquery*

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
$("#button").addClass('button-clicked'); 
 \});

.button-clicked { //you can add this for every page with the color you want 
background: red; <br/>
}
```

**And don't forget to refer to the jquery.js**

Answer (score 0):

So what worked for me was figuring out how to override bootstrap. Understanding the numerical weights of each selector was very useful. This stackoverflow post is what solved my problem: [best way to override bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css)