# How to override a Bootstrap style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radiobuttonlist

How can I do to override an existing class of Bootstrap

The `btn` and `active`class names are added automatically from Bootstrap. I want a specific color on the inset.

```
        <div class="categories">
            <label class="ng-binding">Categories</label>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn active">
                    <input type="radio" name="cat" id="rbOption1"> Cat 1
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn">
                    <input type="radio" name="cat" id="rbOption2"> Cat 2
                  </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've been trying to do this with no positive result

```
.categories label#active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px blue !important";
}
```

Comment: shouldn't pseudo class be with a ":" ?  Looking at your css .categories label#active . Unless you're trying to access the class "active" in which case it would be .active, not #active

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to override bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css)

Comment: @JoeB. I tried also label:active. No success. label#btn:active. No success either

Comment: it's `.active` and remove the `"` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owOgMV

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize that I had a " in my style. Going to the oculist right now.

Comment: lol you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of the question, this is what you have to do in order to override the Bootstrap style.

```
.categories .btn.active {
   box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px blue;
 }
```

If you want to use the same style through out your application or page,

```
.btn.active {
   box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px blue;
}
```

Comment: I tried that also  but the F12 dev tools shows my style as Invalid property value with an icon of warning striking all the style.

Comment: Someone else pointed out my error. I had a " at the end of my style. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Ha ha. :) I already saw that but I thought it's a typo while copy-pasting the code from your source. BTW, you should not use !important unless you've no other workaround.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the comment and I am going to oculist right now. lol!

Answer (score 0):

You can place an id on the label.

**HTML**

```
<label id="active" class="btn">
```

**CSS**

```
#active {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #FF0000;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/awxzwG)