# Why is there an important override on the border classes's color property in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When applying a border to my navigation, I thought it would be best practice to make use of the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) `.border` class.

But looking into the code that will render using this class, it appears to be using an !important value on the color value of the border property inside the `.border` class. In this case I was making use of the `.border-bottom` class to add a border to the bottom of my navigation.

This is what the rendered code would look like when using the class:

```
.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6!important;
}
```

This means if I want to edit the color of this border class, I am required to override the color value with another `!important` value. I was wondering, why is this done like this?

Should I still use the `.border` class for achieving this purpose and override using another `!important` in a custom stylehsheet? Or is the `.border` class not meant for achieving the purpose I am trying to achieve (e.g. I would like a red border instead of whatever white/grey-ish color this is)?

Answer (score 4):

Using `!important` is considered to be acceptable for utility/helper classes, and Bootstrap's authors have [chosen to use `!important`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24836) on *all* of the Bootstrap 4 [Utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/).

This means that the [Border Color utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-color) also use `!important`, and since they follow the other Border classes in CSS file, the `!important` on the color will take precedence ([Example](https://www.codeply.com/go/DykI43kHps)).

If you want to define your own custom border color, then as you said, you will need to use `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using it right, but to change the value of that you probably need to do it in the variable sass file in bootstrap.

Comment: I noticed that Bootstrap also makes use of other coloring classes for the borders such as `.border-danger` which also makes use of `!important`. I just wonder why they're doing it like this. Is there any reason for the use of an `!important` as it seems quite off to me.