# Why does .border-0 override .border-bottom in Bootstrap 4.0.0

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, border

I am having trouble using Bootstrap 4.0.0 utility classes regarding borders.

To be precise, I am encountering some (in my opinion) weird behaviour when applying class="border-primary border-bottom" on an element.
When I check out DevTools in Chrome, I see the following output:

```
.border-primary { // This overrides color assigned from .border-bottom
    border-color: #007bff!important;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6!important;
}
```

The .border-primary acts as if its color declaration overrides .border-bottom color declaration...
Why does this happen when the class .border-primary is set before the class .border-bottom? Shouldn't the latter one override the previous one?
They both have the !important tag and the same specificity (as far as my knowledge goes). The only thing that smells funny is the way we set 
the border color for .border-primary, it seems a little bit more explicit than for .border-bottom class.

Similar problem with borders happens when applying class="border-0 border-bottom" on an element.

When consulting DevTools , it looks like this:

```
.border-0 {
    border: 0!important;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6!important; // This is clearly overridden by border-0
}
```

Basically, instead of denying all borders with .border-0 and then applying border on the bottom by .border-bottom, .border-0 seems to override all and 
remove all borders despite the fact .border-bottom is applied after .border-0 . This kind of opposes the way I thought CSS works.

If I apply class="border-0 border-primary border-bottom" .border-0 overrides .border-bottom, and .border-primary sets the color to primary,which means nothing,since there are no borders because of 
.border-0. Why does all this happen ? Is it a CSS thing, a Bootstrap 4.0.0 thing, or something else ? Please help

I am attaching a JSFiddle example below.

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LukaGrdinic/62pe3bvL/)

Comment: did you check well the CSS ? because `.border-primary` is later than `.border-bottom` .. and `border-0` is latter than `.border-bottom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically answered in [Why is there an important override on the border classes's color property in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479632/why-is-there-an-important-override-on-the-border-classess-color-property-in-boo/49480060#49480060)

As you can see in the docs, the [borders are additive and subtractive](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/#additive). 
The `border--*-0` classes are meant to *remove* borders, either all or specific sides, from an element that already *has* borders such as the card.

The other `border-*` classes are meant to *add* borders.

Therefore, in the case of `border-0 border-bottom`, yes `border-0` removes borders from all sides as intended. In your example, it doesn't make sense to use `border-0` because the `box` doesn't have borders to start with.

If you wanted to only show a `border-bottom border-primary` on an element that already has borders (ie: `card`), you'd use: `border-primary border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0`... `border-primary` to changes the existing border color, and `border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0` to remove the existing border.

Comment: That's because one follows the other in the CSS.

Comment: What bugs me is the fact that when I apply .border-primary before .border-bottom, .border-bottom color gets overridden, even though both classes have the important tag and same specificity.
If I create a custom .my-border-primary class with border-color: blue !important, and set it in the element like this: element class="my-border-primary border-bottom", then .border-bottom would override the color of .my-border-primary 
Why does that happen with my custom class , but bootstrap's class seems to override things. Similar thing applies to border-bottom confusion

Comment: One follows the other, first one is border-primary, second is border-bottom, - Shouldn't border-bottom be the one that overrides ?

Comment: I just realized what you meant by one follows the other in the CSS - order of Bootstrap's CSS is like that: border-bottom CSS code is before border-primary CSS code