# Set body color but div block has different color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a project.
I want to have same background color on body, but when i set body color, div with `.container-fluid` class gets other color.

How can I set same color on both?

**Here is my code:**

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 223, 26);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:rgb(0,223,26)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset-4 col-4 offset-4">
      <div class="offset-1">
        <h1 style="color:rgb(240,255,0)">Random Einstein's Quote Generator</h1>
      </div>
      <b><div class="randomquote" style="font-size:20px">
      </div></b>
      <div class="offset-3">
        <button id="quotegenerator" style="font-size:14px" class="offset-1 col-4 offset-1 btn btn-primary">New Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use  `background-color: rgb(0,223,26)!important;` to prevent override

Comment: In child: background-color: inherit;

Comment: The question is really, why does the child get a different background colour? It shouldn't unless it's explicitly set somewhere. Without seeing the CSS that caused it, we can't point out what the problem is.

Comment: I don't see different background color on `container-fluid`

Comment: tried making `html,body{height:100%}` ?? or maybe something else is overriding the body background color?

Comment: only different color I see is the button color....

Comment: I do not see the issue. Maybe you have some other css or javascript changing the background for `.container-fluid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body style is overridden by the bootstrap CSS , it doesn't take your color:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 223, 26);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
BODY!
</body>
```

You may want to add a div directly inside the body:

```css
body > div {
  background-color: rgb(0, 223, 26);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<body>
<div><!-- Added here -->
<div class="container-fluid"><!-- Removed inline CSS here -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset-4 col-4 offset-4">
      <div class="offset-1">
        <h1 style="color:rgb(240,255,0)">Random Einstein's Quote Generator</h1>
      </div>
      <b><div class="randomquote" style="font-size:20px">
      </div></b>
      <div class="offset-3">
        <button id="quotegenerator" style="font-size:14px" class="offset-1 col-4 offset-1 btn btn-primary">New Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div><!-- Added here -->
<body>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because of the bootstrap css file you're importing. It overrides your body css.

Your solution is to give your body an id of its own.

```
<body id="idForOverrides">
```

Then any css changes you make for that id will override bootstrap's definition.

Learn more here:

[best way to override bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css)

Answer (score 0):

heres is the code for it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style>

 </style>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: green">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset-4 col-4 offset-4">
      <div class="offset-1">
        <h1 style="color:rgb(240,255,0)">Random Einstein's Quote Generator</h1>
      </div>
      <b><div class="randomquote" style="font-size:20px">
      </div></b>
      <div class="offset-3">
        <button id="quotegenerator" style="font-size:14px" class="offset-1 col-4 offset-1 btn btn-primary">New Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can check fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/nnfoy6pw/

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested in firefox and realized that problem is only in chrome

Answer (score -2):

Use  background-color: rgb(0,223,26)!important;