# how to override bootstrap font family?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My custom CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINAlternateBold';
    src: url(./fonts/din/DINAlternateBold.otf);
    }

h4.DINAlternateBold-font {
    font-family: 'DINAlternateBold', sans-serif !important ;
    }
```

html tag

```
<h4 class="DINAlternateBold-font text-uppercase">Dashboard</h4>
```

Currently its showing in console as below, but i want to overwrite with my custom font file

```
font-family": '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif'
```

Comment: review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css

Comment: Your code work perfect (override bootstrap) What you issue?

Comment: the font family is not changing in my html file, it shows this 
font-family": '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif'
in the styles of console. not understanding why it is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that your link to css is after your link to bootstrap which would help you to override it.
For eg:

```html
<html lang="" dir="ltr">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <!-- Your Style -->
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to include in my angular-cli.json file

Answer (score 1):

Accoriding you use `!important` you override bootstrap definition

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINAlternateBold';
    src: url(./fonts/din/DINAlternateBold.otf);
    }

h4.DINAlternateBold-font {
    font-family: 'DINAlternateBold', sans-serif !important ;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h4 class="DINAlternateBold-font text-uppercase">Dashboard</h4>
<h4 class="text-uppercase">I am without override</h4>
```

**But you can do it without `!important` put your stylesheet file link after bootstrap links/scripts**

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
//Your file link
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourStyle.css">
```