# How to change the button color in Strapi admin panel?

Tags: css, strapi

Is there any way to change the primary button color in strapi? This solution is not working for me
[How to override strapis "primary button"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392047/how-to-override-strapis-primary-button)

I tried the option of changing the colors in colors.js. I could change the left menu colors and all, but didn't find any luck with the buttons.