# Recoloring <abbr> tag title in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, abbr

I'm trying to style an abbr tag's title in **[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#abbreviations)**.
But I'm having troubles cause I can't find how to override `bootstrap.css`.

Currently, I am doing this, but the tooltip is not changed:

```css
abbr[title]::after {
  /* content: " (" attr(title) ")"; */
  background-color: indigo;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Pre-mRNA comprises the bulk of <abbr title="heterogeneous nuclear RNA" class="text-info font-italic">hnRNA</abbr>.
</p>
```

Can this be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
abbr:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  background-color: indigo;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Pre-mRNA comprises the bulk of <abbr title="heterogeneous nuclear RNA" class="text-info font-italic">hnRNA</abbr>.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response to my problem. However, the tooltip should be single displayed. There are two tooltips on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This answer by [smugglerFlynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219013/smugglerflynn) will help with overriding and will teach you css priority point values.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27704409/9996381

Id your body tag with `<body id="bs-override">`

Query anything your having trouble overriding with `#bs-override selector`

Also make sure your custom.css is being called after all other .css files.