# How to remove nested link underline and color with CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm unable to change/remove the link underline and color of the nested text. I checked the debug console and the color says it's inherited from a.masonry-item. I tried changing it but it doesn't do anything. If I change the color from the debug console, it does trickle down. What am I doing wrong?

```css
a.masonry-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="masonry-item">
  <div class="card masonry-content">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/450/325?image=100" alt="Dummy Image" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

My expected result is red text with no underline but it has no effect.

Comment: What happens when you define a CSS class for "card-text"?

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: What part would you like what color?

Comment: <h1> and <p>. Preferably I'd like to remove all color and decorations from that <a>

Comment: The reason I'm focusing on a.masonry-item is because the console says that's where it's inherited from.

Comment: There is no `<h1>`. The only elements containing text are `<h5>` and `<p>`. What is supposed to be red? This question is quite unclear.

Comment: My mistake, I meant <h5> and <p>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override Bootstrap CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles)

Answer (score 1):

You can force the removal of any property in CSS by using "!important".

For example:

```
a.masonry-item {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Another user pointed out it's being overridden so I'll have to debug.

Comment: Yes, CTRL-F5 is your friend.