# React bootstrap have to mark every custom class as !important

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a basic form, and I'm finding it impossible to override any bootstrap elements without using !important. For example, a basic form with a first name input, using a custom class "custom-input"

.js

```
<Form>
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <Form.Group>
         <Form.Control
            type="name"
            placeholder="First Name"
            className="custom-input"
          />
      </Form.Group>
   </Col>
 </Row>
</Form>
```

.css

```
.custom-input{
    border: 0
}
```

This **does not** remove the border unless I add `!important` to it. Why does it require !important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to battle the default classes with custom classes. You can use dev tools and see how it renders on the front-end and style those classes. For example:

```
<Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
  <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />     
</Form.Group>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label" for="formBasicEmail">Email address</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter email" type="email" id="formBasicEmail" class="form-control">
</div>
```

So you can just write the css:

```
.form-control {
    border: 0;
}
```

This way you can style what they use in react bootstrap components instead of trying to override every style. This way you do not have to use `!important`

Or you can double check to see that your css is below the bootstrap styling so you can override the style.

Comment: This. This is it. I couldn't figure out which classes to override, as far as I could tell it was a guessing game! But using the inspector I can seel form-control. But form-control didn't work, I had to use ```.form-group .form-control```, so how many parent levels up should you usually go? And is there any reference for bootstrap react that has this information, or is it trial & error with the developer console?

Comment: I mean three is a general suggestion I have heard from other developers. It is a lot of trial and error though

Answer (score 1):

#### You need to understand how CSS style apply order works. Basically there are four rules:

> - inline css overrides css rules in style tag and css file
> - a more specific selector takes precedence over a less specific one
> - rules that appear later in the code override earlier rules if both have the same specificity.
> - A css rule with !important always takes precedence.

Also, there are selector weights which priorities styles:

> - 1000 points inline styling
> - 100 points for IDs
> - 10 points for classes and pseudo-classes
> - 1 point for tag selectors and pseudo-elements

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css) for more details how CSS apply order works. 
Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles) for how to customize bootstrap in right way.

Comment: I definitely understand this. Read it 50x, but no one tells you which classes to override is the issue and how do you know even which classes to override