# How to add custom CSS stylesheet when using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My custom CSS stylesheet are not working when I use Bootstrap.
**!important** tag doesn't work (I also heard !important is not a good practice)
and
Using ID instead of Class is not a good idea as style will be used multiple times.

Is there a way to override Bootstrap without using ID?

HTML with bootstrap and custom css linked

```
 <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-custom">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Jake Yoon</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

custom css

```
.navbar-custom {
   background-color: lightsteelblue;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override Bootstrap CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles)

Comment: Include your CSS after Bootstrap, and if you are overriding any of Bootstraps styles make sure you use a selector that is at least as specific (i.e. it has the same full selector)

Comment: I've seen the post before but didn't really help me because using ID was not a good idea. I understand what you're saying about choosing selector Thanks!

Comment: There are other answers apart from the id too, just because one is accepted doesn't mean that its the only one to look at :) And the first comment on the accepted answer suggest making the id a class, exactly like the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best answer. But this is how I manage :

```
<div class="bootstrap-classes eg.navbar">
     <span class="custom-classes">hello world</span>
</div>
```

Use bootstrap classes in parent. Create a child and use your own classes on it. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the key word

```
important!
```

to override the bootstrap class.
an example is given below

```css
 .navbar-custom {
   background-color: lightsteelblue !important;
   font-size: 25px !important; 
   color: white !impotant;
}
```

```html
 <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-custom">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Jake Yoon</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

This only you want to change the CSS file.