# Overriding Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I recently referenced a bootstrap css in my code like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

However, I do not like the border it puts on `.card` elements. I tried to override the bootstrap and remove the border by inserting `style="border: 0"` into the card div, but it didn't do anything.

```css
.card {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card card-sm" id="localcard">
  <p> See Thin Border </p>
</div>
```

How can I remove this border?

Comment: Add a custom stylesheet that you link to after bootstrap, then rewrite the class there to override the base bootstrap one.

Comment: @NathanielFlick could you show an example? I am new to css, and don't really know what that means

Comment: Yep this has been answered very well already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles

Comment: read the doc : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of custom style, use built-in class : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card card-sm border-0" id="localcard">
  <p> See, no  Border! </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `!important` tag in the css like this:

```css
.card {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card card-sm" id="localcard">
  <p> No Border </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use important. To override Bootstrap (or any CSS) you need to rewrite the style to be loaded after Bootstrap (further down the global cascade).

Comment: Use boostrap class before firing an  !important ;)