# How to input a class that have more than one class in CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to put the class that have more than one class into my css, for examples I have this code in my html.

```
class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end"
```

And I want to change all of the above to disappear so I have to put "display: none". I have tried this in css but it doesn't seems to work.

```
.nav nav-pills justify-content-end{
    display: none;
}
```

Ps: I use bootstrap framework

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles

Comment: write it like this `.nav.nav-pills.justify-content-end`. No spaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

There are different way you can do this operation .
you can use `comma Operator(,)` ,you can use no space between all all class `.nav.nav-pills.justify-content-end` like this and you can choose any of class and make `display: none;` like this

```
.justify-content-end{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.nav.nav-pills.justify-content-end{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `coma operator(,)` to add the same style to deferent classes

```css
.nav,.nav-pills,.justify-content-end{
    display: none;
}
```