# Remove default padding-left and padding-right in container-fluid while from Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I wanted to remove default padding-left and padding-right in container-fluid. I am using bootstrap 5.
Refer to the screenshot. I have disabled by default padding-left and padding-right and then I have got my desired result using chrome dev. tools. I don't want to use "!important" in CSS file.
I have also tried no-cutter class with container-fluid and I have also tried g-0 to remove gutters in container-fluid but still it doesn't work. Though "!important" in css file with

```
    .container-fluid{
          padding: 3% 15% !important;
    }
```

did worked but I don't wanna use this solution. If there is any other way to resolve this issue using Bootstrap 5.

```css
/*********************************TAG SELECTOR***************************/
h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/*********************************CLASS SELECTOR***************************/
.navbar-brand, .nav-item{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.container-fluid{
  padding: 3% 15% !important;
}

/*********************************ID SELECTOR***************************/
#title{
  background-color: #ff4c68;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- Added Ubuntu & Montserrat font from Google font -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Added CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Added CSS bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Added Javascript bootstrap-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Features -->
  <section id="features">
    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
  </section>

  <!-- Testimonials -->
  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

    <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


    <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    <h2>Free</h2>
    <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
    <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Labrador</h3>
    <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
    <p>Pirority Listing</p>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you tried p-0 class ??

Comment: @FtMohak Can you show your `head` tag here you have linked your `bootstrap` and `styles.css`.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman where to add "p-0" class?

Comment: container-fluid p-0

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman it didn't work.

Comment: would you show up wt expected result u need exactly ? as per your question you need to remove default padding, so using p-0 class sets padding to 0 in Bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `styles.css` should follow `bootstrap.min.css` in the HEAD tag. Once this is done the `.container-fluid` padding override you've set will take precedence...

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- Added Ubuntu & Montserrat font from Google font -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Added CSS bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Added CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>
```

https://codeply.com/p/3VrA65Nv72

Also see: [How can I override Bootstrap CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles/52049168#52049168)