# Twitter Bootstrap's Element Border Color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, attributes, overriding

I want to change the border color of any element when it gets focused from blue to green. The problem is I don't know the attribute name I should change to override this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Below is an image for better comprehension:

[image]

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820952/change-bootstrap-input-focus-blue-glow#answer-14822905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, look for @input-border-focus, enter your desired color code, scroll down and click "Compile and Download".