# Bootstrap Form border gradient

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

By default, clicking on a Bootsrap Form will display a gradient of color on the borders.

[image]

Is there a way to modify the bootsrap.css or bootsrap.js to **display an other color for the gradient?**

Here is a Fiddle with the example on the picture above: https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/122/

And the code:

```css
#form-default {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
#form-green {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="form-group">

  <select id=form-default name="Form1" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Form1</option>
    <option value="1">Option2</option>
    <option value="2">Option3</option>
  </select>

  <select id=form-green name="Form2" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Form2</option>
    <option value="1">Option2</option>
    <option value="2">Option3</option>
  </select>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in this answer..

[Change Bootstrap input focus blue glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820952/change-bootstrap-input-focus-blue-glow)

Override the `.form-control:focus` blue glow..

```
.form-control:focus {
      border-color: #FF0000;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/123/

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to override this bit of CSS by bootstrap:

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66AFE9;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0px 0px 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

The *blue* part of the gradient is `rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6)`, so change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
.form-control:focus, .form-control:active, .form-control:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will alter the border color. The box-shadow changes the gradient portion. Adding :focus makes it occur only when you have it selected.

```
#form-default:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px green;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .form-control
  {
   border-color: rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.8) !important;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6) !important;
   outline: 0 none !important;
  }
 .form-control:hover
  {
     border-color: blue !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the  `.form-control:focus` blue glow..

`.form-control:focus{
webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,0.6);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,0.6);
}`
to change above color code