# How to remove the outline of the clicked option in bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, bootstrap-select

Good day ladies and gentlment of stackoverflow. I would just like to ask if how could i remove the blue border when I click the one of the options in my select-bootstrap select tag.
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the code block? Nobody can answer by just providing a hint about the problem...

Comment: Please share your code ...

Comment: That's just an `outline` property in `css`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Bootstrap input focus blue glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820952/change-bootstrap-input-focus-blue-glow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this css:

```
a, a:active{
    outline: none!important; 
}
```